# Binomial series of an expression. Can't find an approach.

Tags: complex-analysis, binomial-theorem

I am currently trying to understand and implement a method from a paper. Inside the method there is an integral I have to solve by hand. I got the result in form of a series expansion but I don't understand the way to get to this result.

The integral is

\begin{align}
\int\limits\left[\left(t-a_1\right)\cdot\left(t-\bar{a}_1\right)\cdot\left(t+a_1\right)\cdot\left(t-\bar{a}_1\right)\right]^{\frac{1}{2}}\frac{dt}{t^2}
\end{align}

with $a_1=e^{k\pi i}$ and $\left\{k\in\mathbb{R}|0\le k\le\frac{1}{2}\right\}$ and the complex conjugate $\bar{a}_1$. The paper says the result is a serial expansion in the form of

\begin{align}
\int\limits\left[1-\frac{1}{2}\left(a_1^2+\bar{a}_1^2\right)\frac{1}{t^2}-\frac{1}{8}\left(a_1^2-\bar{a}_1^2\right)^2\frac{1}{t^4}+\ldots\right]dt
\end{align}

It looks as if the expression in the first formula can be transformed to something similar to the binomial series $\left(1-\frac{1}{x^2}\right)^{\frac{1}{2}}$ but right now I have no idea how. I tried to several approaches, for example

\begin{align}
&\int\limits\left[\left(t^2-a_1^2\right)\cdot\left(t^2-\bar{a}_1^2\right)\right]^{\frac{1}{2}}\frac{dt}{t^2}\\
=&\int\limits\left[\left(t^4-\left(a_1^2+\bar{a}_1^2\right)\cdot t^2+a_1^2\cdot\bar{a}_1^2\right)\right]^{\frac{1}{2}}\frac{dt}{t^2}\\
=&\int\limits\left[\left(1-\frac{\left(a_1^2+\bar{a}_1^2\right)}{t^2}+\frac{a_1^2\cdot\bar{a}_1^2}{t^4}\right)\right]^{\frac{1}{2}}dt
\end{align}

but I still can't find a way to obtain the series expression. Even if $a_1\cdot\bar{a}_1=1$ I still have

\begin{align}
&\int\limits\left[\left(1-\frac{\left(a_1^2+\bar{a}_1^2\right)}{t^2}+\frac{1}{t^4}\right)\right]^{\frac{1}{2}}dt
\end{align}

In my opinion I got one term too much in the integrand. Is there a way to get rid of the term with $t^4$?

Could someone please show me a way? What am I missing?

The integral and series expansion can be found in [MilneThomson](http://ing.unitn.it/~bigoni/varie/MilneThomson.pdf) on page 153.

Comment: **hint:** $(a+b)(a-b)=a^2-b^2$

Comment: Thanks, I tried that, but from $\int\limits\left[\left(t^2-a_1^2\right)\cdot\left(t^2-\bar{a}_1^2\right)\right]^{\frac{1}{2}}\frac{dt}{t^2}$ I still have no idea how to get to something in the form of $(1-x)^{\frac{1}{2}}$ of the integrand.

Comment: You can edit your original question if you are still having difficulty.

Comment: Sorry to interrupt but is $a_1=\pm1$?

Comment: Well, $a_1=e^{k\pi i}$, so $|a_1|=1$

Comment: Do you think this answers my question? (Unrelated: please use @.)

Comment: @Did Sorry, I don't understand your question. $a_1=e^{k\pi i}$ with $\left\{k\in\mathbb{R}|0\le k\le\frac{1}{2}\right\}$. So $a_1=1$ for $k=0$. The problem comes from the Schwarz-Christoffel-mapping of a unit disk to a rectangle. The integral and series expansion can be found in http://www.ing.unitn.it/~bigoni/varie/MilneThomson.pdf on page 153.

Comment: Now you answered the question: $k$ is not supposed to be an integer but a real number hence $a_1$ can be any complex number on the (first quadrant of the) unit circle.

Comment: @Did right. Forgot to mention that. Sorry.